# CSS center content inside div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to center html content inside a div class="partners" (top div with 2 images). As you can see from the image below (it floats left instead of center of the div):

[image]

This is my html code:

```
<div id="partners">
    <div class="wrap clearfix">
        <h2>Partnertnerzy serwisu:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.dilbert.com/"><img width="56" height="16" alt="Parnter bar wika" src="/as/partners/wika.png"></a></li>    
            <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com><img width="65" height="15" alt="Parnter bar siemens" src="/as/partners/siemens.png"></a></li>    
        </ul>
        <a class="linkClose" href="/firmy?clbp=1">Zamknij </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image:
[image]

CSS:

```
#partners, #top {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
#partners {
    margin: 12px 0 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
.clearfix:after, .row:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#partners .wrap {
    width: 655px;
}
.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 990px;
}
#partners h2 {
    color: #A6A5A5;
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 2px 15px 0 0;
}
#partners ul {
    float: left;
}
ul {
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your css code formatting. The code is not enough to understand the positioning of the `#partner` container. - I'd say you need a wrapper around the containter and specify the following center it `#partner_wrapper { text-align: center; } #partner { display: inline-block; }`. You can reset this formatting for child elements `#partner * { text-align: left; }`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

To center a div, set it's width to some value and add margin: auto.

```
#partners .wrap {
    width: 655px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

EDIT, you want to center the div contents, not the div itself. You need to change display property of `h2`, `ul` and `li` to `inline`, and remove the `float: left`.

```
#partners li, ul, h2 {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
}
```

Then, they will be layed out like normal text elements, and aligned according to text-align property of their container, which is what you want.

Comment: My mistake, you wanted to center the contents, not the div itself. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 32):

There are many ways to center any element. I listed some

1. Set it's width to some value and add margin: 0 auto.

```css
.partners {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

2. Split into 3 column layout

```css
.partners {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

---

3. Use bootstrap layout

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Your Content / Image here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 29):

You just need

```
.parent-div { text-align: center }
```

Answer (score 15):

Try using flexbox. As an example, the following code shows the CSS for the container div inside which the contents needs to be centered aligned:

Depending on the axis of the flexbox, you will need to align or justify items, read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

```
.absolute-center {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: won't work if you expect your html to be shown in an email client like GMail

Answer (score 9):

in parent div

```
parentDiv: {
     display:flex;
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     justify-content:center;
     align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: This worked well !

Answer (score 5):

You just do CSS changes for parent div

```
.parent-div { 
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you assigned a fixed width to your .wrap DIV. The DIV itself is centered (you can see that when you add a border to it) but the DIV is just too wide. In other words the content does not fill the whole width of the DIV.

To solve the problem you have to make sure, that the .wrap DIV is only as wide as it's content.

To achieve that you have to remove the floating in the content elements and set the `display` property of the block levels elements to `inline`:

```
#partners .wrap {
 display: inline;
} 

.wrap { margin: 0 auto; position: relative;}

#partners h2 {
color: #A6A5A5;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 2px 15px 0 0;
display: inline;
}

#partners ul {
display: inline;
}

#partners li {display: inline}

ul { list-style-position: outside; list-style-type: none; }
```

Comment: This answer includes an explanation behind the correct instructions. More answers ought to be like this!

Answer (score 2):

do like this :

```
child{
    position:absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After 2022.
Here is your class to center content both vertically and horizontally.

```
.center {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```