# I want to center some buttons inside a div html

Tags: html, css, grails

I am really new at css and I'm having serious trouble dealing with the css, I'm using grails to do a proyect but I have this div

```
<div class="header">
<g:link controller="history" action="create" class="headerButton">New Consult</g:link>
<g:link controller="patient" action="list" class="headerButton">Patient</g:link>
<g:link controller="history" action="list" class="headerButton">Search</g:link>
</div>
```

I want these buttons to be centered inside the div I tried everything with the css, but it's not working always sticked on the left

Any solution??

Comment: add a border to your div then you can visually see why.

Comment: I hope this could resolve your problem,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926540/css-center-content-inside-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS use `div.header{text-align:center;}`, e.g. see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVgyD/1/).

Comment: this jsFiddle is amazing you solve a lot of problems from now on thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.header{text-align:center;}
```

or

```
<div style="text-align: center;" class="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<div style="text-align: center;" class="header">Your Buttons</div>

or

<style>
   .header {text-align: center;}
</style>
```