# Centering multiple divs (not grouped) within div

Tags: html, css

I'm simply trying to center a block of divs (within a div) but I cannot seem to center it. I've tried [solutions from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926540/css-center-content-inside-div), but none of them work for me?

**Structure**:

```
<div id="content" class="email-prefs">
   <div class="item"><!-- content -- ></div>
   <div class="item"><!-- content -- ></div>
   <div class="item"><!-- content -- ></div>
   ....
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated! P.s. I'm trying to center the `.item` div

```css
#content {
  text-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.email-prefs .item {
  width: 27.0%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #36383d;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.subscribe-options {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="email-prefs">

    <p class="header">Uncheck the types of emails you do not want to receive:</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="subscription_ids" value="">

    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-inner  selected">
            <div class="checkbox-row">
                <span class="fakelabel">
                    <input id="id_896974" type="checkbox" name="id_896974" checked="checked">


                    <span>Food for Thought instant blog notification</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <p>Be the first to read our new liveRES blog posts</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-inner  selected">
            <div class="checkbox-row">
                <span class="fakelabel">
                    <input id="id_1044442" type="checkbox" name="id_1044442" checked="checked">


                    <span>Food for Thought monthly blog roundup</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <p>Must-read moments from the liveRES blog</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-inner  selected">
            <div class="checkbox-row">
                <span class="fakelabel">
                    <input id="id_4811083" type="checkbox" name="id_4811083" checked="checked">


                    <span>Industry insights and research</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <p>Keep on top of the latest hospitality facts and figures</p>
        </div>
    </div>





  



  <div class="subscribe-options" style="margin-right: 0">
    <p class="header">Or check here to never receive any emails:</p>
    <p>
      <label for="globalunsub">
                              <input name="globalunsub" id="globalunsub" type="checkbox">
                              <span>
                                  Unsubscribe me from all mailing lists.
                              </span>
                          </label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="hs-button primary" id="submitbutton" value="Update email preferences">

  <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you float them left? remove that and it should work.  If you want line space after each, then either use a br or make them block with margin auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to wrap `.item` in a wrapper and set `text-align: center` to that wrapper
- Remove `float` from `.item` and set `vertical-align: top`

```css
#content {
  text-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.item-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
.email-prefs .item {
  width: 27.0%;
  /* float: left; */
  /* margin: 0; */
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #36383d;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.subscribe-options {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="email-prefs">

  <p class="header">Uncheck the types of emails you do not want to receive:</p>
  <input type="hidden" name="subscription_ids" value="">

  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner  selected">
      <div class="checkbox-row">
        <span class="fakelabel">
                                      <input id="id_896974" type="checkbox" name="id_896974" checked="checked">
                                      
                                      
                                      <span>Food for Thought instant blog notification</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <p>Be the first to read our new liveRES blog posts</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner  selected">
      <div class="checkbox-row">
        <span class="fakelabel">
                                      <input id="id_1044442" type="checkbox" name="id_1044442" checked="checked">
                                      
                                      
                                      <span>Food for Thought monthly blog roundup</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <p>Must-read moments from the liveRES blog</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner  selected">
      <div class="checkbox-row">
        <span class="fakelabel">
                                      <input id="id_4811083" type="checkbox" name="id_4811083" checked="checked">
                                      
                                      
                                      <span>Industry insights and research</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <p>Keep on top of the latest hospitality facts and figures</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>





  



  <div class="subscribe-options" style="margin-right: 0">
    <p class="header">Or check here to never receive any emails:</p>
    <p>
      <label for="globalunsub">
                              <input name="globalunsub" id="globalunsub" type="checkbox">
                              <span>
                                  Unsubscribe me from all mailing lists.
                              </span>
                          </label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="hs-button primary" id="submitbutton" value="Update email preferences">

  <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a common div with class **flex** for all the three items and add the following styling for it

```
.flex{
display:inline-flex;
justify-content: center
}
```

and Remove the following css from **email-prefs .item** class

```
.email-prefs .item {
 /*margin: auto;Remove this line*/
}
```

```css
#content {
  text-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.flex{
display:inline-flex;
justify-content: center
}
.email-prefs .item {
  width: 27.0%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #36383d;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*margin: auto;Remove this line*/
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.subscribe-options {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="email-prefs">
   <p class="header">Uncheck the types of emails you do not want to receive:</p>
   <input type="hidden" name="subscription_ids" value="">
   <div class="flex">
   <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner  selected">
         <div class="checkbox-row">
            <span class="fakelabel">
            <input id="id_896974" type="checkbox" name="id_896974" checked="checked">
            <span>Food for Thought instant blog notification</span>
            </span>
         </div>
         <p>Be the first to read our new liveRES blog posts</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner  selected">
         <div class="checkbox-row">
            <span class="fakelabel">
            <input id="id_1044442" type="checkbox" name="id_1044442" checked="checked">
            <span>Food for Thought monthly blog roundup</span>
            </span>
         </div>
         <p>Must-read moments from the liveRES blog</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <div class="item-inner  selected">
         <div class="checkbox-row">
            <span class="fakelabel">
            <input id="id_4811083" type="checkbox" name="id_4811083" checked="checked">
            <span>Industry insights and research</span>
            </span>
         </div>
         <p>Keep on top of the latest hospitality facts and figures</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="subscribe-options" style="margin-right: 0">
      <p class="header">Or check here to never receive any emails:</p>
      <p>
         <label for="globalunsub">
         <input name="globalunsub" id="globalunsub" type="checkbox">
         <span>
         Unsubscribe me from all mailing lists.
         </span>
         </label>
      </p>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="hs-button primary" id="submitbutton" value="Update email preferences">
   <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want it like this?

Just removed `float:left;`

```css
#content {
  text-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.email-prefs .item {
  width: 27.0%;
  
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #36383d;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.subscribe-options {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="email-prefs">

  <p class="header">Uncheck the types of emails you do not want to receive:</p>
  <input type="hidden" name="subscription_ids" value="">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner  selected">
      <div class="checkbox-row">
        <span class="fakelabel">
                                      <input id="id_896974" type="checkbox" name="id_896974" checked="checked">
                                      
                                      
                                      <span>Food for Thought instant blog notification</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <p>Be the first to read our new liveRES blog posts</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner  selected">
      <div class="checkbox-row">
        <span class="fakelabel">
                                      <input id="id_1044442" type="checkbox" name="id_1044442" checked="checked">
                                      
                                      
                                      <span>Food for Thought monthly blog roundup</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <p>Must-read moments from the liveRES blog</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner  selected">
      <div class="checkbox-row">
        <span class="fakelabel">
                                      <input id="id_4811083" type="checkbox" name="id_4811083" checked="checked">
                                      
                                      
                                      <span>Industry insights and research</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <p>Keep on top of the latest hospitality facts and figures</p>
    </div>
  </div>





  



  <div class="subscribe-options" style="margin-right: 0">
    <p class="header">Or check here to never receive any emails:</p>
    <p>
      <label for="globalunsub">
                              <input name="globalunsub" id="globalunsub" type="checkbox">
                              <span>
                                  Unsubscribe me from all mailing lists.
                              </span>
                          </label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="hs-button primary" id="submitbutton" value="Update email preferences">

  <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should **explain** WHY your code works. Also, try adding `vertical-align-top` to the inllne-block divs.

Comment: I did explain... Just removed the float. Also, I don't add codes to answer which is not actually mine

Comment: No.. that explains WHAT you did...not WHY the elements are now centered.

Comment: I don't want to be rude or anything, but I'd like to ask why you are asking only me to explain? The other two users who answered didn't explain either, they also just mentioned what they did.